# Use of overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous problem

Tags: c++

I am writing python input() analog in c++.
scan() can read string and char, but i have problem with string:

Use of overloaded operator '=' is ambiguous (with operand types 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits, allocator>') and 'scan')

How can i fix it to be able to read chars and strings?

```
struct scan {
    operator string() {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        return s;
    }
    operator char() {
        char c;
        cin >> c;
        return c;
    }
};

void solution() {
    char c;
    c = scan();
    string s;
    s = scan();
}
```

Comment: The issue you are facing is due to the ambiguity in the assignment operator when using the `scan` struct. Since the `scan` struct has conversion operators for both `std::string` and `char`, the compiler cannot determine which one to use when assigning the result to a variable of type `string`. To fix this, you can add a member function to explicitly read a string using `scan`.

Comment: @IshaanAdarsh Can you elaborate why it won't choose the first conversion operator for strings and the second for chars?

Comment: @jabaa `std::string` has [overloads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) of `operator=` for both `char` and `std::string`. So both conversions from `scan` involve exactly one user-defined conversion, and neither one is better than the other for the purposes of overload resolution.

Comment: In C++, when the compiler sees a statement with multiple possible conversions, it gets confused about which one to choose. It can't tell if it should use the first conversion operator for strings or the second one for chars. This leads to an ambiguity error, and the compiler doesn't know what to do. To overcome this you could add a member function to explicitly read a string or a char

Comment: Why you overload operators at all? Is there some reason for it? In this case it makes code harder to read and maintain. This is good example of overengineering .

Comment: @IshaanAdarsh -- the compiler doesn't get confused; it knows the rules, and it refuses to make things up. <g>

Comment: @IshaanAdarsh oh i got it! Thanks! But can you please show an example of code how to fix it? I don't understand how to write it :(

Comment: Sure i will post it in a minute.

Comment: @MarekR I am writing template for competitive programming to do things such as
`generate(a.begin(), a.end(), input())`. where input():

`scan input() { return scan(); }`

Comment: @PeteBecker Okay, I was taught that it gets confused. But makes sense that it consciously doesn't make a specific decision.

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel: `std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{std::cin}, 5, a.begin());`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator

Comment: @MarekR well i expected that it was in c++, thanks for an answer! But i think i really want to reinvent the wheel, just for fun :)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I agree wholeheartedly. It's better you focus on development or OSS or anything else really in which you actually learn something and could produce some real output.

Comment: `c = scan().operator char();` and `s = scan().operator string();`, and Bob's your uncle!

Comment: "I am writing python input() analog in c++." I don't understand how the code shown relates to this task. `input` in Python only ever produces a string, and Python does not have a separate character type, so there is no reason to have a separate overload to read a `char`. Aside from that, it makes absolutely no sense to use a type-conversion `operator` to actually do the work of reading input. The entire point of these operators is that they convert the *current* state of the object, and if repeatedly called on the same object will give the same result.

Comment: Trying to make the behaviour of a call depend on the type of the variable being assigned to, simply does not make sense (and is again not a thing that emulates Python, because Python's variables do not have type). It only works in certain languages like Perl, in a limited capacity, and only because of special syntactic features of those languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to the ambiguity in the assignment operator when using the `scan` struct. Since the `scan` struct has conversion operators for both `std::string` and `char`, the compiler cannot determine which one to use when assigning the result to a variable of type `string`. To fix this, you can add a member function to explicitly read a string using `scan`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct scan {
    operator string() {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        return s;
    }

    operator char() {
        char c;
        cin >> c;
        return c;
    }

    // New member function to read a string explicitly
    string readString() {
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        return s;
    }
};

void solution() {
    char c;
    c = scan();
    scan s; // Create an instance of scan
    string str;
    str = s.readString(); // Use the new member function to read a string
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve the ambiguity with using direct initializations:

```
void solution() {
    char c{scan()};
    string s{scan()};
}
```

There is no such a string constructor that takes `char` at the first parameter, thus the ambiguity goes away.